# Why didn't anyone find the explosion tags hidden in Konoha earlier?

Tags: naruto

I am referring to the filler episode (Episode 200 of *Naruto*), where a Trap user named Gennō was on a mission to destroy Konoha by planting millions of explosive tags throughout the village while he disguised as a carpenter.

The tags were found 30 years after it was planted.
Why did they find it now?

**Meanwhile in Konoha, there were the Hyuga clan who were Byakugan users. Why didn't they at least accidentally find one or two in millions of the explosive tags that were hidden in Konoha?**

Comment: Can you give the specific episode number?

Comment: By amulets, do you mean *explosive tags*? Gennō had later revealed at the end that those tags were deactivated. So, finding and removing millions of already deactivated tags were a troubling act. Plus, since the tags were deactivated, the Hyuga couldn't detect it. Have to ask though, where was it mentioned that he had planted it 30 years back?

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Yes I do mean explosive tags. and it was in naruto episode number 200

Comment: @EroSɘnnin it is mentioned in the episode that he planeted them during the reconstruction of konoha. Although I'm not sure if it is 30 years back thought it was after the kyubii incident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to take a few things into consideration there.

1. Explosive tags do have only a bit of chakra compared to the chakra of the average Ninja. Thus with Ninjas all around......it is as if you are not looking for the tree with the eagle sitting upon it while walking through a forest. Even with their Byakugan active there were just so many chakra signatures.....stronger even that if they didn't look exactly for a low signature such as from a tag....they wouldn't really have noticed it.
2. The tags were not active at the time being. Thus the chakra was inactive and thus "stagnant". Which means that there was maybe a very small chakra signature to see for a Hyuga and others who can feel chakra.....but it didn't do anything. As we know every human produces chakra too. So again it could be explained by just noting that if there is something small that does nothing (a bee sitting on a flower) while you are passing others near you (wasps flying around you) you are not going to really put any conscious notice to the small bee.
3. As we know time and again from the series the Byakugan is not infallible. There seem even to be seals that can block their usage. The best example being Naruto himself. If he did not ACTIVELY use the kyubis chakra (aka let it out of the seal).......no Hyuga even noticed something different about him (compared to others that is). Sadly it is not 100% clear if that is the nature of seals in general or if there are special seals which makes chakra that is not actively set free/used invisible to Hyugas (which is more plausible, as the Hyugas then later on in the episode the OP mentioned find the tags).

All in all it is plausible that the hyugas did not see the tags (small, static chakra while big moving chakra sources are all around them).

The only thing that baffled me about the episode is thus not that it was not noticed.....it was more the MASS of tags he had. As we know they are not THAT cheap to buy/manufacture.  Thus he almost used a stockpile that must have been worth a kages yearly income (or more). And also how he got them into the city unnoticed. That much paper probably WOULD have been noticed by someone. 
But as far as I'm aware there was no reference in that one episode to how he managed to do these two things.